# Wondering what the word "bear" mean here

Tags: word-meaning

This faith (religion) **bears** a strong bond to the nation Turkey.

Based on my perception it has nothing to do with a close relationship !

Comment: Although this question seems to be answerable by a dictionary, I understand the OP's difficulty to identify the meaning of [bear a bond](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bear). I think "bear a bond" here is used figuratively as in "carrying or supporting a weight". Although you can find uses of "bear a bond" I wouldn't say is the best collocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear simply means "carry" in this case. Like in "the right to bear arms". It can, however, be used in a figurative way, as is the case in your sentence.

Something can be said to "bear a resemblance to something", meaning it resembles something.

In your sentence, the religion *has* a strong bond with the nation.

It is a bit archaic, poetic language.

Comment: *It is a bit archaic, poetic language.* Generally, yes. But in phrases like "bear a stong bond to" or "bear a resemblance to" it is idiomatic and still in common use.

Comment: In bear a resemblance, yes. I'm not sure I have encountered "Bear a strong bond" before today :)